# Unconventional technique (hack) I can use on my OfficeJet Pro 9015 in order to make it print with only the new full black cartridge completely full

Tags: printer, colors

Around August, 2020, I purchased an OfficeJet Pro 9015 printer

It already came with black & color cartridges.

Almost all the times I printed, I always selected the following option:

"Print in Greyscale:  Black Ink Only"

Only in rare cases will I ever print in color, and it was very rare.

However, around last week, the printer stated that Cartridges were depleted.

I navigated through HP printer menu in order to retrieve more specifics about printer cartridge status.

I found it really strange that they showed the following statistics:

- Cyan  -  Low
- Magenta  - Low
- Yellow   - Empty
- Black  - Empty

I can understand that Black cartridge is empty, but I rarely used the other colors.

Note: I do have a new Full black cartridge that I can use to replace the empty black cartridge.

Also, HP corporation cunningly implemented their printers to Only work if all the cartridges had some ink in them so if any of them are found to be empty then it Never prints.  Really sneaky.

1. Why did the Yellow become empty and also why did Cyan and Magenta are so low?(Does Not make sense because I rarely print color
2. Does anyone know of any kind of unconventional technique (hack?) I can use on my OfficeJet Pro 9015 in order to make it print with Only the new Full black cartridge completely full while the other colors are low or empty

Comment: If you never purchased color ink, you most likely are a victim of the sample size ink cartridges that comes with printers.  The printer uses small amounts of your color ink even when you print Black and White.  Which is the reason mono is better (yes, there is a difference between the two settings).

Comment: Are you saying that the color ink cartridges that came along with the brand new printer when I purchased it have lower amount of ink in them?(i.e. HP just cheated me LOL)  Is that it?

Comment: @crazyTech Yes. They give you small capacity cartridges when you buy a new printer. Simple as that. They charge you less for the printer than what it is worth, skimp on the ink and make money when you buy replacement cartridges that are marked up. The inkjet business is a scam. This [Consumer Reports article](https://www.consumerreports.org/printers/why-is-printer-ink-so-expensive/) doesn’t completely explain what I just wrote, but worth reading for details on how the actual business of inkjet works.

Comment: @crazyTech - You bought a printer not ink cartridges

Answer (score 1):

Inkjet printers are renowned for wasting ink. Many printers waste as much ink as they deposit on the paper. Ink of all colours is used whenever the printheads are purged. That happens not only when you clear a blocked jet, but also every time the printer powers up or wakes up from sleep.

So yes, even if a cartridge is never used, it will be depleted after enough power cycles.

Some printers can be told to print with black only when the colour cartridges are empty, but most (including yours) do not let you do that. Here is the [official HP statement](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04331666) for a large number of their printers, including the OfficeJet Pro 9015.

Comment: More details on the world of inkjet economics here at [Consumer Reports](https://www.consumerreports.org/printers/why-is-printer-ink-so-expensive/).